# Go bufio.Writer, gzip.Writer and upload to AWS S3 in memory

Tags: go, amazon-s3, buffer, gzip, newline

I am attempting to write a compressed file from memory and upload to S3.

I am serializing a large array of `type Data struct` into a `bufio.Writer` that writes to a `gzip.Writer` in a line-by-line fashion:

```
### DATA AND SERIALIZATION

type Data struct {
  field_1 int
  field_2 string
}

func (d *Data) Serialize() []byte {
  return []byte( fmt.Sprintf(`%d;%s\n`, d.field_1, d.field_2) )
}
```

```
### CREATE FILE AS COMPRESSED BYTES

var datas []*Data   // assume this is filled

buffer := &bytes.Buffer{}
compressor := gzip.NewWriter(buffer)
writer := bufio.NewWriter(compressor)

for _, data := range datas {
  writer.Write(data.Serialize())
}

writer.Flush()
compressor.Close()
```

```
### UPLOAD COMPRESSED FILE TO S3

key := "file.gz"
payload := bytes.NewReader(buffer.Bytes())

upload := &s3.PutObjectInput{
  Body:   payload,
  Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
  Key:    aws.String(key),
}
```

This works, seems fast and somewhat efficient.

However, the resulting file, although considered a text file under Linux, does **not honor the line breaks** added via `\n`. Not sure if this is an OS specific issue, an issue with defining the file type by some means (e.g. use a file format ending `file.txt.gz` or `file.csv.gz`, or by adding specific header bytes), or an issue with the way I am creating these file in the first place.

What would be the proper way to create a fully qualified in-memory file type as `[]byte` (or inside an `io.ReadSeeker` interface  in general) to upload to S3, *preferably* in a line-by-line fashion?

---

**Update:**

I was able to solve this by wrapping the string in a call to `fmt.Sprintln`:

```
func (d *Data) Serialize() []byte {
  return []byte( fmt.Sprintln(fmt.Sprintf(`%d;%s`, d.field_1, d.field_2) )
}
```

When looking at the implementation of `fmt.Sprintln` it appends the `\n` rune - there must be subtle differences I am not aware of.

Comment: `does not honor the line breaks added via \n`. Is this the issue? What does it mean?

Comment: @ZekeLu I am adding the `\n` newline character at the end of each serialized string in order (or rather, in hopes) to create lines in the resulting file. That part does not work, neither `cat` not text editors consider the file to be written in lines - all data is on a single line when opened either way. File is written and read on Linux. Apparently, my appending to the buffered gzip writer does not correspond to appending lines to a file...

Comment: The result file is gzip'ed. You should un-gzip it first to get the text content.

Comment: @ZekeLu *of course* I am unzipping it! The data is there, just not formatted into lines. I.e. when opening that file in whatever way, the data looks like this `field_1;field_2\nfield_1;field_2\nfield_1;field_2\n...`, written out on a *single line*. So, to make this absolutely clear: Excel-likes open this file with all data in the first row - 'correctly' delimited into columns when specifying `;` as delimiter. Sublime outputs *a single line* with all that data in it. `cat` does, too.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I have taken a carefully look and found that `\n` is in a raw string literal and it means a character "\" and a character "n" instead of a new line. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
`%d;%s\n`
```

with

```
"%d;%s\n"
```

**`%d;%s\n`** is a raw string literal. And in a raw string literal, backslashes have no special meaning. See [String literals](https://go.dev/ref/spec#String_literals) in the language spec:

> Raw string literals are character sequences between back quotes, as in `foo`. Within the quotes, any character may appear except back quote. The value of a raw string literal is the string composed of the uninterpreted (implicitly UTF-8-encoded) characters between the quotes; in particular, backslashes have no special meaning and the string may contain newlines.

Comment: *That* is a good catch - I should have looked there myself the second this issue surfaced...thanks a lot! It works perfectly. I assumed using ` by default is a no-brain free pass out of escape hell - turns out it takes the no escaping serious...